# iOS app always uses (wrong) localization

Tags: ios, internationalization, xcode8

I have an app that is designed with an English user interface and additionally got a German UI translation. When running, the correct user interface language is chosen. Base Internationalization is used, Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3.

Then I cloned the app into a new one, mainly stripping off parts and renaming the app. This was quite a PITA (sorry) with the main problem being CocoaPods not recognised anymore (error on `import`) etc. After some fiddling it works again, but the UI is *always* in German(!), regardless of the iOS Settings. Even if iPhone language is English, with no other preferred languages, and region is United States, the app UI shows up in German.

Strangely, the strings used in the app (via `NSLocalizedString()`) are correctly chosen in English.

`Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first` also returns `en`.

Addendum:
The system dialogs presented by the app are in English.
The key `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` is set to `en` in `Info.plist`.
The UI texts in `Base.lproj/Main.storyboard` are in English.

Same behaviour on simulator and real devices.

I suspect that the English (Base) UI has become kind of unavailable during the process. However, in Interface Builder the English version is shown as "Main Storyboard > Main Storyboard (Base)" with a sibling file "Main.strings (German)" containing the translation.

Addendum 2: In Project → Info → Localizations, I can see "English — Development Language: 2 Files Localized" but "German: 5 Files Localized". Maybe that's the reason why some resources are not available in English at runtime. But I cannot determine which files are meant by the entries.
If I "Export for Localization", I get an `xliff` file with these 5(!) headers (`XY` being the project name):

```
  <file original="XY/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" target-language="de">
  <file original="XY/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" target-language="de">
  <file original="XY/Info.plist" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" target-language="de">
  <file original="XY/Localizable.strings" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" target-language="de">
  <file original="XY/Main.strings" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" target-language="de">
```

Any hints?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Franck: unfortunately, no. But fortunenately I was able to skip the whole project. Maybe I'll try it again with the new Xcode 9.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations` to `yes` in your Info.plist

Comment: Worked for me! 
I'm storing localized strings in shared framework and this option did the trick

Answer (score 3):

You may have to edit your scheme. Next to your Build / Run and Stop Buttons, click on your Application and click **Edit Scheme**.

In the window that pops up, make sure you're on the Run Tab.

Now in the **Run** Tab, there should be 4 other Tabs in there (**Info**, **Arguments**, **Options**, and **Diagnostics**) - make sure you're on the **Options** Tab!

In the **Options** Tab, scroll down and you should see **Application Language**. In my case Application Language was set for Spanish which made it so that no matter what, my app would build localizing with the Spanish language. Changing **Application Language** to **System Language** made it so that the builds work as expected, working with whatever language my device is using at the time.

Hope this helps someone!